# Tomcat 7.0.27 died without trace

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

A while ago I tried to install artifactory 2.6.1 on ubuntu 12.04 on an EC2 instance of 512m memory. But when I started it, after initialization it just quit quitely. I installed it on a ubuntu 10 with 3g memory, and it works.

Now I'm installing another web application on that small instance, it worked fine. But when our db was loaded with more data, tomcat quit without trace. Although it still works on the bigger instance.

Since artifactory and my web app behaves the same, I tend to blame tomcat. Why tomcat dies without error output? Is it really memory related?

Thanks.

Comment: Once you have identified OOMKiller, this really helped me to : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128642/debug-out-of-memory-with-var-log-messages

Answer (score 7):

The only way Tomcat will stop without error output is if something issues a kill -9 . If you didn't do this then the Linux OOME killer may have. Check /var/log/messages.

Other ways Tomcat stops should all generate output of some form:

- An OOME will trigger a log message. Check the log files including catalina.out
- A clean shutdown will be obvious in the logs since you see the standard closing down messages
- A JVM crash will not show up in the Tomcat logs but you should see a JVM crash dump in whatever the current working directory was for the Tomcat process
- Other fatal exceptions will trigger log messages like an OOME

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at /var/log. I had this confirming that I ran out of mem :
Aug 24 09:11:25 low-mem-host kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 28862 (java) score 268 or sacrifice child
Aug 24 09:11:25 low-mem-host kernel: Killed process 28862, UID 498, (java) total-vm:5365052kB, anon-rss:2177828kB, file-rss:152kB